# Can this schematic protect my load cell/strain gauges from lightning?

Tags: surge-protection, tvs

Today I was soldering gas discharge tubes (GDTs) to one of my PCBs used in a column load cell.

I found the placement of the GDTs very odd as the main aim of GDT is to protect load cell or strain gauges from lightning.

Below is the schematic showing the placement of the GDTs.

Please guide me whether the placement of GDTs protects the load cells or strain gauges from lightning.

[image]

Comment: First, you should explain what damage has occurred and how the load cell was mounted.

Comment: Nothing will protect against direct lightning. That leaves you with working to a recognized specification for indirect lightning such as [EN 61000-4-5](https://www.emcstandards.co.uk/handbook-on-en-61000-4-5-testing-and-measureme). So define what your limits are and then you have a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your circuit will not provide a good protection, below is the better solution with trisil/transzorb/gdt. But even this won't protect your cell from destruction.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2VT6J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The best protection you can have for a load cell, that supports a construction is an earthing strip, bolted between two construction ends.

[image]

Look here the copper strip mounted:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marko... Your sample schematic and the image cleared my doubts leading to change in my circuit or rather implementation of lightening arresters for my sensors.